# Problem with PHP MYsql Delete syntax with timestamp comparison

Tags: php, mysql

All I am trying to do is delete rows in a column that have a timestamp more than 2 days old.

I have tried a lot of things I have seen on here, but none of them seem to be working.

This is the code:

```
$delquery = $tapeDB->query('DELETE FROM newsItems WHERE news_date < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,NOW());
```

These are the errors I am getting on that line:

> Warning: Unexpected character in
>   input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in...
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING in...

This should be really easy but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where are you closing the ('') ?

Comment: I don't see a closing quote on that query string...

Comment: Ok, i put an endquote, but that wasn't the problem, still get this error:  Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

DELETE FROM newsItems WHERE news_date < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,NOW()


Line Number: 232

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot the closing quote

```
$delquery = $tapeDB->query('DELETE FROM newsItems WHERE news_date < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,NOW()');
```

Comment: oh and use an IDE, they are really helpful :)